# How to cover Exception block using Moq in Ms Unit test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, c#-4.0, moq

Can anyone please help me in covering exception using moq in MS Unit Test.
Here is my Sample controller method

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("DeleteEnumeration")]
    public int DeleteEnumeration(TemplateDto template)
    {
        try
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<DBFrameworkBL>();
            container.RegisterType<DBFrameworkDal>();
            container.RegisterType<IDBFrameworkDal, DBFrameworkDal>();
            DBFrameworkBL objDBFrameworkBL = container.Resolve<DBFrameworkBL>();
            return objDBFrameworkBL.DeleteEnumeration(template);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogUtilities.LogException(ex);
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Here is my sample Test method

```
  [TestMethod]
    public void Test_DeleteEnumerationMocking()
    {
        TemplateDto template = new TemplateDto();
        template.Template_Name = "Speed-enum.xml";
        template.Template_Type = "Enumeration";
        template = null;
        Mock<IDBFrameworkBL> moq = new Mock<IDBFrameworkBL>(
                                                       MockBehavior.Strict);
        moq.Setup(m => m.DeleteEnumeration(template)).Throws(new Exception());
        DBFrameworkController dbFramewoek = new DBFrameworkController();
        dbFramewoek.DeleteEnumeration(moq.Object, template);
    }
```

Getting an error that DeleteEnumeration does not take stwo arguements.
Can anyuone suggest me better solution or how to mow this test case since m new to c#.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot wrong with the method under test as it appears to be mixing implementation and cross-cutting concerns. Hints at some serious design flaws.

Ideally a BL abstraction should be injected into the controller and not resolved locally. The container and all the dependency registrations should be moved to the composition root keeping the controller simple.

```
public class DBFrameworkController: ApiController {
    private readonly IDBFrameworkBL objDBFrameworkBL;

    public DBFrameworkController(IDBFrameworkBL objDBFrameworkBL) {
        this.objDBFrameworkBL = objDBFrameworkBL;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("DeleteEnumeration")]
    public int DeleteEnumeration(TemplateDto template) {
        try {
            return objDBFrameworkBL.DeleteEnumeration(template);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LogUtilities.LogException(ex);
            return 0;
        }    
    }
}
```

This would allow for the test to mock the desired behavior, like throwing the exception.

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeleteEnumeration_Should_Throw_Exception() {
    //Arrange
    var template = new TemplateDto();
    template.Template_Name = "Speed-enum.xml";
    template.Template_Type = "Enumeration";

    var mock = new Mock<IDBFrameworkBL>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    mock.Setup(_ => _.DeleteEnumeration(template)).Throws(new Exception());
    var controller = new DBFrameworkController(mock.Object);
    var expected = 0;

    //Act
    var actual = controller.DeleteEnumeration(template);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```